# Get common root of String path and list of folders for that path

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I've SQLite3 database table where I store a list of paths like this:

```
/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file1
/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file2
/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file3
/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file4
/mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b/file5
/mnt/sdcard/folder1/e/c/file6
/mnt/sdcard/folder2/d/file7
/mnt/sdcard/folder2/d/file8
/mnt/sdcard/file9
```

What I want to do is to find the common root of these paths and to get the list of first level folder (unique) of that common root.

For example

First run: parent root = null (it's the first run)
common root -> /mnt/sdcard/
List of folders
- folder1
- folder2

Second run (now parent root will be /mnt/sdcard/folder1/)
common root -> /mnt/sdcard/folder1/ (same as parent root)
List of folders
- a
- e

Second run (now parent root will be /mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/)
common root -> /mnt/sdcard/folder1/a/b (same as parent root)
List of folders -> empty (I'll get files)

Is there a way to do those filters by db or I have I to do that by code?

This question is made because I need to provide a Folder View of Android Music Library that store paths in the song db record.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Find_common_directory_path

It's implemented in some programming languages.

This is the Java example I've tested and used for my purposes.

```
public class CommonPath {
    public static String commonPath(String... paths){
        String commonPath = "";
        String[][] folders = new String[paths.length][];
        for(int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++){
            folders[i] = paths[i].split("/"); //split on file separator
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < folders[0].length; j++){
            String thisFolder = folders[0][j]; //grab the next folder name in the first path
            boolean allMatched = true; //assume all have matched in case there are no more paths
            for(int i = 1; i < folders.length && allMatched; i++){ //look at the other paths
                if(folders[i].length < j){ //if there is no folder here
                    allMatched = false; //no match
                    break; //stop looking because we've gone as far as we can
                }
                //otherwise
                allMatched &= folders[i][j].equals(thisFolder); //check if it matched
            }
            if(allMatched){ //if they all matched this folder name
                commonPath += thisFolder + "/"; //add it to the answer
            }else{//otherwise
                break;//stop looking
            }
        }
        return commonPath;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] paths = { "/home/user1/tmp/coverage/test",
                 "/home/user1/tmp/covert/operator",
                 "/home/user1/tmp/coven/members"};
        System.out.println(commonPath(paths));

        String[] paths2 = { "/hame/user1/tmp/coverage/test",
                 "/home/user1/tmp/covert/operator",
                 "/home/user1/tmp/coven/members"};
        System.out.println(commonPath(paths2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe outline briefly why the link particularly applies to this question? The link might become invalid and then your answer would not be helpful anymore...

Comment: Of course, @der_michael, I found this thread searching for same question because I thought the algorithm should be implemented and posted anywhere. I updated my answer with the Java example from the rosettacode wiki.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to do the same thing, but in C#.  Here's my solution to finding a common root directory.  You should be able to adapt it.

```
        public static string GetCommonRoot( params string[] paths )
    {
        int minDepth = 999;
        List<string[]> parsedPaths = new List<string[]>();
        foreach( string p in paths )
        {
            string[] parts = p.Split( '\\' );
            parsedPaths.Add( parts );
            minDepth = parts.Length < minDepth ? parts.Length : minDepth;
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for( int i = 0; i < minDepth; i++ )
        {
            List<string> tmp = new List<string>();
            foreach( string[] dir in parsedPaths )
            {
                tmp.Add( dir[ i ].ToLower() );
            }

            if( !AllEqual( tmp.ToArray() ) )
                break;

            sb.AppendFormat( "{0}\\", tmp[ 0 ] );
        }

        return sb.ToString();

    }

    private static bool AllEqual( params string[] strings )
    {
        bool rv = true;
        for( int i = 1; i < strings.Length; i++ )
            rv &= strings[ 0 ] == strings[ i ];

        return rv;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it by code.
We need tree data structure here.
Lets create class Folder

```
Folder{
 List<String> fileList;
 List<Folder> folderList;

}
```

Now algorithm:
1.Get list of paths in List pathList

2.split first string in list with delimiter "/". you will get array of Strings, say array1 First element in this array will be name of root folder. create root Folder. next elements in array will be subfolder . Last element will be filename

3.for remaining paths in pathList. split each path. u'll get array, say array2. Now iterate array1 & array2 in parallel till u find that array1[i]!=array2[i].

If inequality found, and you are at last element of array2, it means its file in existing folder. add it to list. if you are not at last element, you will need to create folder.
This will create tree of folders.

Comment: I don't want to query the file system. I've a list of paths in the db and I want to find an alg to get the informations I asked in the question :) I've already made the "filesystem solution" and it's not optimized

Comment: Tomorrow I'll give a try, I hope it wont be too heavy with more than 5k songs

Comment: it might get heavy. if you are sure that path will be always in sorted order,you can try some optimization techniques.

Comment: I was also thinking that maybe a good solution is to use a Tree that implements the structure where nodes are folders and leafs are files (songs)

Comment: If u observe, this algorithm is creating tree like structure only.Just that we are not naming it tree. Here Folder are nodes and File are leaves. There can be multiple folders and files in selected folder, hence we are using list for both.

Answer (score 0):

The open source Java library [path-pattern-finder](https://path-pattern-finder.github.io/) provides a function to find the common directory roots of paths.

```
import com.owenfeehan.pathpatternfinder.commonpath.FindCommonPathElements;
Optional<Path> commonPath = FindCommonPathElements.findForFilePaths(paths);
```

It can also be used more broadly to find certain naming-patterns among paths (sequence of numbers, constant substrings etc.).

Full disclosure: I'm the author of the library.